# jQuery UI: How can I have more than one "selectable" element if the element has to have id="selectable"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

All of the demo's ive been able to find follow this pattern:

```
<ol id="selectable">
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    ..
</ol>
```

[jQuery UI selectable demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#default)

I've tried changing the ID of the list to something unique but it doesn't seem to work. Is it a requirement that the selectable element have and id of "selectable" and if so, how can you make more than one list selectable?

Comment: I have run into this as well.  If I change the `id` from `selectable` to something else it stops working.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I did not think about the CSS that actually changes the color...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a requirement to use an id. In fact, you aren't required to use html lists either.

The following example uses a `<div>` as the container and `<span>` elements as the selectable items.

```
<div class="group">
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
  <span>Item 3</span>
</div>

<script>
  $(".group").selectable({ filter: 'span' });
</script>
```

The next example uses a data attribute selector `[data-album]` to target multiple containers. Each of these `<p>` elements will be converted into a separate selectable with their child `<img>` elements as selectees.

```
<p data-album="Vacation">
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
</p>


<p data-album="Birthdays">
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
  <img src="..." />
</p>

<script>
  $("[data-album]").selectable({ filter: 'img' });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The operational code is:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
});
```

You can replace `#selectable` with any selector that points to what you want to make selectable. So it doesn't have to be an ID. It could be a class like `.selectable`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class instead of an element. An element's class can contain multiple value.

Answer (score -2):

Just change te line

```
¥('selectable').selectable();
```

To

```
¥('idChosed').selectable();
```

For each element you choosed